# How to set Stylus option to respect @import "sheet.css" directives for broccoli-stylus-single

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

Not sure how to set options for the Stylus CSS pre processor. A search of all the files reveals this:

`node_modules/broccoli-stylus-single/node_modules/.bin/stylus [98]:`
`node_modules/broccoli-stylus-single/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus [98]:`

```
/**
 * Include CSS on import.
 */

 var includeCSS = false;
```

Does anyone know the correct/preferred way to set this option to 'true' in Ember-CLI framework / Broccoli build system?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this maps to `"include css": true` in the `options` map ([source](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/1f34ade6225c92d55c67d08424db8d8e82db219a/lib/visitor/compiler.js#L33)):

```
var Compiler = module.exports = function Compiler(root, options) {
  // ...
  this.includeCSS = options['include css'];
  // ...
};
```

I've tested this with `ember-cli-stylus` and it appears to work.